# Postman Post data to a page that required login

Tags: http, postman

is that possible to post a data to a page that require login? Example, I develop a web and in a route `http://localhost:3000/forum/post` is use a middleware to access it. So, is possible to using postman to login first to my web and post to an auth page?

Comment: So, this URL redirects to a login page, right? What kind of login is it? Can you not directly bypass this by entering all the login info yourself in the request? `Postman` has auth features also but I don't think that would work in your scenario.

Comment: Is this a general question, or specific to your target website? If it is general, you need to investigate the authorization logic and check "session id", "token" etc in the HTTP request & response. Then, simulate it in the Postman yourself. If it is specific, please provide more detail information.